# Do descriptions from functions after exporting get deleted?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor, documentation

So lets say i have this really nice function i want to export with a const are:

```js
export const are = {
 
 you: function(){
   ...
 }
}
```

And now lets say i added a decription to it that discribes what it does:

```js
export const are = {
 /**
 * This functions does stuff :D
 */
 you: function(){
   ...
 }
}
```

Whilest you can view the description from this script, it seems as though when it has been exported and reimported into another script it loses its description. Lets say i have this script called script.js:

```
import * as run from "run.js"
//and now lets say i call the function
run.are.you()
//when you type .you it just says the default text for a function
```

If you try exporting it seperately like

```js
import {are} from "run.js";
are.you()
//when you type .you it still says the default text for a void function
```

Just to note I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Basically to sum up are you asking why comments are removed when you import it from another file?

Comment: @mrtechtroid yes

Comment: Its just because the comments are for helping the user to add descriptions to various parts of code. They are not parsed or even touched by the Browser. So When you import them the browser only imports the function excluding all the comments as they dont contribute anything to the function from the browser's standpoint.

Comment: @mrtechtroid ty for the information but another thing i was going to ask is how do i add this comment to basically describe what my function does, maybe somehow within the function and then after you parse it onto the other script you can still read it

Comment: I Guess You Can Use Variables to store them for now. But my question is why do you want this comment to be present when you are importing it from another file? Cant you just read this comment in that file?

Comment: I could but the entire point of this is so that if someone was to use that function in their own script they could read it without having to search that file :|

Comment: Even if someone uses this function in their own script wouldn't they have access to the source script also? From where they are getting the function? So they can read it from there itself. (if importing, they know exactly where the function is located). if they are using the function using Copy Paste they can copy the comment along with it.  Also A Best Practice while Coding is For Code To Be Self Explanatory.

Comment: As ive said "without having to search that file" its just that i want to make a custom library so having knolage like that would be very helpful